# make new dataframe meeting a specific criteria

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with four variables (a,b,c,d) and 365 entries per variable

df

```
a     b     c       d
a1    b1    c1     d1 
.     .     .       .
.     .     .       . 
a365 b365  c365   d365
```

I need to do two things:

1) Select the row where which meets the criteria of d > 0.28 and a > 2.3. I did this using this:

```
cond_1 <- d > 0.28 & a > 2.3
```

Lets say, the first row which meets the criteria is row 7. How can I make a new data frame starting row 7 onwards and discarding the rows prior to row 7? ( I need to include all row after 7th row irrespective of whether they meet the criteria or not)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this for example:

```
df[seq(min(with(df,which(d > 0.28 & a > 2.3)))+1,nrow(df)),]
```

Comment: thanks  a lot for this. It is doing the job perfectly. But I am not sure why +1 in ....+1, nrow(df)),] is added. It excludes the first row which meets the criteria (row 176) and actually selects the dataframe from 177 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[which(df$d > 0.28 & df$a > 2.3)[1]:nrow(df),]
```

Comment: I am new to R but I checked the code and its working fine.. can you please point out what I did wrong

Comment: I am terribly sorry. Forgot the $ symbol. Thanx